# Асинхронность в FastAPI / Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность, multiprocessing, fastapi

Как сделать, чтобы при получении, например, двух запросов в FastAPI, они выполнялись независимо друг от друга. То есть, если первым придет запрос на обработку, который занимает 20 сек, а вторым придет запрос, который занимает 5 сек, то результат второго запроса возвращался раньше первого? В данный момент имеется такой пример (в async функциях yield/thread/multiproccessing не присутствуют):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host= host, port= port, log_level="info", loop="asyncio")


@app.post("/bar_logo")
async def add_bar_logo(pos: str = Form(""), fio: str = Form(""), phone: str = Form(""), date: str = 
Form(""), file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    file_data = file.file.read()
    res_pdf = await bar_logo(file_data, pos, fio, phone, date)
    return FileResponse(res_pdf, media_type="application/pdf", filename=file.filename)


async def bar_logo(file_data, pos, fio, phone, date):
    uuid = uuid4()
    doc = fitz.open(stream=file_data, filetype="pdf")
    if doc[0].rect.width > doc[0].rect.height:
        l_path = await draw_bar_w(pos, fio, phone, date)
        with open(l_path, "rb") as f:
            logo = fitz.Pixmap(f.read())
    else:
        l_path = await draw_bar_h(pos, fio, phone, date)
        with open(l_path, "rb") as f:
            logo = fitz.Pixmap(f.read())
    doc[-1].insert_image(doc[-1].rect, pixmap=logo)
    save_dir = f"../results/{uuid}.pdf"
    doc.save(save_dir, garbage=2, deflate=True, encryption=encrypt_meth, permissions=perm, owner_pw="")
    return save_dir
```

Comment: Получилось ли решить задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Есть асинхронные фреймворки, есть синхронные. В целом идея такая: асинхронные по умолчанию выполняют все запросы в 1 потоке, синхронные выполняют каждый запрос в отдельном потоке.
Если писать на async, то никаких доп задержек быть не должно, как cpu bound так и io bound без async.

`async def` - не значит, что функция выполняется асинхронно.

Посмотрев на ваш пример, можно увидеть что `async def bar_logo` - синхронно читает из файловой системы => io задержка, которая блочит весь event loop. Блокировка event loop = все клиенты ждут.

Вот и получается, что 1 запрос прилетел и так как там блочится event loop, все остальные запросы не могут быть обработаны. Это очень грубо, но в общем работает это примерно так.

---

Чтобы этого избежать нужно использовать специальные асинхронные либы, [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) например для чтения файлов.

А вот если либы специальной нет, то все io вещи нужно заворачивать в потоки.  Можно присмотреться к [anyio](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/threads.html) библиотеки, которая облегчит тут жизнь.

```py
from anyio import to_thread


async def io_bound(io_fun, params_fun):
    await to_thread.run_sync(io_fun, params_fun)
```

Потоки - хорошо подходят для io bound задач и плохо подходят для cpu bound задач, где требуются вычислительные ресурсы. Это связано с существованием GIL. 
Поэтому для cpu bound задач можно использовать процессы.

Вот очень простой пример:

```
async def cpu_bound(fun_cpu_bound, params_fun):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, fun_cpu_bound, params_fun)
```

Comment: Какое преимущество в использовании `anyio.to_thread` по сравнению с `asyncio.to_thread`?

Answer (score 0):

Базовый пример, выполняется асинхронно.

```
import asyncio

import uvicorn as uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/one")
async def read_root():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    return {"first_root": "one"}


@app.get("/two")
async def read_item():
    return {"second_root": "two"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#create-it

Comment: Это ясно, когда мы используем асинхронную функцию. Нужен более реальный пример, как мне самому написать такую функцию?

Comment: Это что ни есть реальный пример) 
await asyncio.sleep(10) - вместо этого кода делаете свою функцию.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы я переписал ваш код?

Comment: Ваш ответ не связан с моим вопросом. Вопрос больше связан с использованием функций в которых имеется asyncio.get_event_loop() и дальнейшая работа с loop (либо другие аналоги). 
"await asyncio.sleep(10) - вместо этого кода делаете свою функцию." - как мне сделать свою функцию наподобие asyncio.sleep?

Comment: Ну как это не связан - вы спрашиваете про то, как сделать асинхронные урлы. await def [имя вашей функции](): код вашей функции.

Comment: **async def** и это так не работает, потому что функция все равно будет блокирующей. Возможно кто-то поможет нам решить этот момент

Comment: Можете уточнить ваш вопрос, возможно я его не правильно понял?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122489/discussion-between-andrew-holovko-and-r4d1f).